# How do I import a file containing styles in react native?

Tags: typescript, react-native

For example in my project there are a few Input elements in different files. The styling of the Input elements has to be the same in all the files. The styling of the Input elements are written in a different file(`Input.ts`) in theme/components folder like this:

```
import { spacing } from "theme/spacing";
import { colors } from "theme/colors";
import { InputProps } from "react-native-elements";
import { typography } from "theme/typography";

export const Input = {
containerStyle: {
    marginVertical: spacing.small
},
errorStyle: {
    marginLeft: spacing.tiny,
    marginBottom: 0
},
inputContainerStyle: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: colors.palette.offWhite,
    borderRadius: typography.size * 2,
    paddingVertical: 0
},
inputStyle: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    fontFamily: typography.primary,
    color: colors.text,
    lineHeight:typography.size * 1.5,
    textAlignVertical: 'center',
    fontSize: typography.size,
    paddingLeft: typography.size,
    paddingVertical: spacing.small
},
leftIcon: {
    size: typography.size,
    color: colors.dim
}
} as InputProps;
```

I want to use these styles in `login.tsx` file:

```
<Input placeholder="Email" />
```

But I don't understand how to import this `Input.ts` file or use this `Input.ts` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
// inputStyles.ts
import {StyleSheet} from "react-native";

export default StyleSheet.create({
  containerStyle: {
    marginVertical: spacing.small,
  },
  errorStyle: {
    marginLeft: spacing.tiny,
    marginBottom: 0,
  },
  inputContainerStyle: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: colors.palette.offWhite,
    borderRadius: typography.size * 2,
    paddingVertical: 0,
  },
  inputStyle: {
    alignSelf: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    fontFamily: typography.primary,
    color: colors.text,
    lineHeight: typography.size * 1.5,
    textAlignVertical: "center",
    fontSize: typography.size,
    paddingLeft: typography.size,
    paddingVertical: spacing.small,
  },
  leftIcon: {
    size: typography.size,
    color: colors.dim,
  },
});

// login.tsx
import inputStyles from inputStyles.ts

<Input placeholder="Email" style={inputStyles.inputContainerStyle} />
```

Comment: The earlier syntax was ```export const Input = { .....} as InputProps; ```. Was the earlier syntax wrong?

Comment: It's not wrong, as in it'll work, but there's just no need for it. You're only exporting one thing from that file, so it's more conventional to export it as the default (also removing the need for a variable name inside the module itself). This does change the import syntax from `import { thingYoureImporting } from .....` to `import thingYoureImporting from ....`.

Comment: inputContainerStyle has a borderWidth of 1. But the border is showing in the login screen.

Comment: You need a borderColor as well